# What the difference between <= and = in cocotb?

Tags: hdl, cocotb

It seem that I can use indifferently <= or = to set an input signal value on my design.
Is there a real difference between two ?

```
dut.button_in = 0
```

or

```
dut.button_in <= 0
```

I have exactly the same output chronogram.

Comment: This `<=` symbol usually means "smaller than or equal". I know nothing about cocotb but I'm guessing it should probably mean the same as it does pretty much everywhere else.

Comment: no, <= is for value assignation. Same as VHDL. But I wonder if there is a difference between <= and simple =.

Comment: Well, I stand corrected, then. I'm guessing there should be a difference...

Comment: some more [here](https://github.com/potentialventures/cocotb/issues/526)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer can be found [here](https://github.com/potentialventures/cocotb/issues/526).

There is no fundamental difference between <= and = except that = can ovewrite the reference and <= is only used for value assignement.

[AlexanderSpirin](https://github.com/AlexanderSpirin) give some examples to illustrate the problem :

```py
@cocotb.test()
def parallel_example(dut):
    reset_n = dut.reset
    dut.reset = 1        # OK
    dut.reset <= 1       # OK hdl-like shortcut for the next one 
    dut.reset.value = 1  # OK 
    reset_n <= 1         # OK
    reset_n.value = 1    # OK
    reset_n = 1          # Doesn't work: reference overwrite
```

Thanks to [Vinay Madupura](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5466496/vinay-madapura) for the clue.